# ng-src not working properly but src is working fine

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to add an image to a sample web page. But whenever I use ng-src in img tag, the image is not showing on the page (the image is visible if I use 'src' in place of 'ng-src').
Here is my Html and JavaScript file.

Javascript & HTML :

```js
/**
*  Module
*
* Description
*/
angular.module('myModule', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.clicked = "";
        $scope.clickMe = function() {
            $scope.clicked= "Image Clicked";    
        };
    }]);
```

```html
<html ng-app="mainModule">
<head>
    <title>Testing For Image Click</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="container" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div>
        <img ng-src="bluegem.jpg" ng-click="clickMe()"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to use `ng-src` at all? You are using a hard-coded image path, so `src` is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2-3 problems in this code
1. myModule and mainModule(your app.js is creating a module named myModule but in your html you are using mainModule)
2. order of mentioned files (angular.js should be mentioned before app.js
Here I am adding the code

```
<html ng-app="myModule">
<head>
    <title>Testing For Image Click</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

    Latest compiled and minified JavaScript
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->


</head>
<body class="container" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div>
        <img ng-src="{{image}}" ng-click="clickMe()"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

And

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.clicked="";
        $scope.image = "bluegem.jpg"
        $scope.clickMe=function()
        {

            $scope.clicked="Image Clicked"; 
        };
    }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the markup so that the ng-src binds to a variable and not a URL as you had it setup before:

```
<img ng-src="{{imageURL}}" ng-click="clickMe()"/>
```